# Executing query when running migration - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm not sure if a migration is the best solution, but I'll explain my problem ...

I need to run a routine to populate a new column in the database, basically this routine will grab all records that have no value executing function that goes popular ...

This script will only be used once, right after I add the column that will be null by default, after adding the column it will populate the fields ...

Note: The table already has records

What is the best way for me to achieve the expected result?

I tried:

```
public function up()
{

    $allCategories = Category::where('slug', null)->get();

    foreach($allCategories as $singleCategory ){
        $singleCategory->update([
            'slug' => Category::makeSlug( $singleCategory->name, $singleCategory->parent_id)
        ]);
    }
}
```

But this does not working

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Anything in `storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Comment: This isn't a great use for a migration although I don't know why it wouldn't work.  I think this should be a `Seeder` or just an Artisan command that you run after the migration.

Comment: no mistakes

But I figured out why it was not filling .... forgot to mark the field as filable ..

Sorry, beginner error, rsrs

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to add data to your new fields in your new migration. I'm not sure if it's the best way to go, but I've seen something like this before:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('my_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('my_column')->nullable();
    });
    $this->updateData();
}

private function updateData()
{
    $allCategories = Category::where('slug', null)->get();

    foreach($allCategories as $singleCategory) {
        $singleCategory->update([
            'slug' => Category::makeSlug($singleCategory->name, $singleCategory->parent_id)
        ]);
    }
}
```

Assuming your Category model is namespaced and `Category::makeSlug()` exists, this should update your `null` slugs.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why it was not filling .... forgot to mark the field as filable on model ..

Sorry, beginner error, rsrs